# How can I get dbt working on my Mac targeting Databricks

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, databricks, dbt

I use my Macbook Pro to develop DBT Models against Databricks. Everything was working well enough, but I couldn't leave well enough alone and recently ran "dbt update" and saw that a bunch of things were outdated. I had run into issues in the past where upgrading my Python (install via Brew) broke things so I avoided upgrading Python, but upgraded SQLite. Apparently, an upgrade Python was a dependency and upgraded Python. So, DBT no longer works.

After lots of searching, I ran

```
brew remove dbt
brew install dbt
```

since the `brew install dbt` told me that installing dbt-labs/dbt/dbt has been deprecated, I instead ran `brew install dbt-postgre` figuring I will get the core DBT files install this way.

then per https://github.com/databricks/dbt-databricks, I ran

`pip install dbt-databricks`

All seemed mostly well except for the standard warning about "distutils config files is deprecated", etc...

Now, I run `dbt debug` and I get

```
Running with dbt=1.2.2
dbt version: 1.2.2
python version: 3.9.14
python path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/dbt-postgres/1.2.2/libexec/bin/python
os info: macOS-12.6-arm64-arm-64bit
Using profiles.yml file at /Users/andrewpark/.dbt/profiles.yml
Using dbt_project.yml file at /Users/andrewpark/iCloud Drive (Archive)/Documents/Work >Projects/Github Source/data-platform/transformation/databricks-dbt/dbt_project.yml

18:24:13  target not specified in profile 'databricks_sql', using 'default'
18:24:13  Error importing adapter: No module named 'dbt.adapters.databricks'
Configuration:
  profiles.yml file [ERROR invalid]
  dbt_project.yml file [OK found and valid]

Required dependencies:
 - git [OK found]

1 check failed:
Profile loading failed for the following reason:
Runtime Error
  Credentials in profile "databricks_sql", target "default" invalid: Runtime Error
    Could not find adapter type databricks!
```

I haven't touched my profiles.yml file at all so nothing there has changed, but it says the file is invalid. It appears to me that the **dbt-databricks** adaptor is not being found. How can I resolve this?

OS: MacOS Monterey 12.6
Python Version: 3.10.7
DBT Version (Core): 1.2.2

Also, I had installed dbt-snowflake and dbt-postgres adaptors as well as dbt-databricks, but these adaptors don't appear when I run `dbt --version`, only the Postgres 1.2.2 plugin.

Answer (score 0):

configure profile.yml

```
your_profile_name:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: databricks
      catalog: 
      schema: 
      host: 
      http_path: 
      token:
```

Comment: Hello @Romerito Morais, thank you for your response. My profile.yml is already configured that way with the correct host, http_path, and token defined for the SQL Warehouse/Endpoint. As I have mentioned above. My CLI version of DBT used to run against Databricks fine before the Python upgrade.